# change the access tier of file blob storage from hot tier to archive tier in ADF pipeline

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I would like to copy my files from one container to another container using ADF pipeline and while copying i have to changes of Access tier from Hot tier to archive tier.

I have to achieve this using ADF pipeline. Help me a way with out using custom activity would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a direct property in any activity to achieve this, you can try one of the methods from below.

Using [Web activity in Azure Data Factory and Azure Synapse Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-web-activity)

1. [Copy Blob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/copy-blob) where, **x-ms-access-tier**  Specifies the tier to be set on the target blob.
2. If after the `CopyActivity`, use [Set Blob Tier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/set-blob-tier), **x-ms-access-tier** Indicates the tier to be set on the blob

Of course you would have to use parameters to make this dynamically executable for multiple files involved.

Comment: but this way i have to change tier for all files everytime instead i need to change to the files i am copying.

Comment: and moreover these are work in same storage account. i have to copy files to other storage account by changing tier

Comment: I see from the docs, "storage accounts created on or after June 7th, 2012 allow the Copy Blob operation to copy from another storage account."

Comment: as you want to achieve through adf pipeline.

Comment: After copy activity > you can have a loop, which iterates through the source files and builds the dynamic URL, which you can use in parameterized WebActivity call to change the blob tier. Or you would have to use  [Lifecycle management policy definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/lifecycle-management-overview#lifecycle-management-policy-definition) and do a already created custom [policy assignment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/assign-policy-rest-api#create-a-policy-assignment) using WebActivity REST API

Comment: Refer: [Setting or changing a blob's tier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/access-tiers-overview#setting-or-changing-a-blobs-tier)

Comment: i have done this but file is creating but not content of the file..

Comment: you are using hierarchical namespace right ? enabled ADLS 2. Is it that there are additional empty files created or the copied target file itself is empty ?

Comment: empty files created with the filenames from source. yes ADLS

Comment: And it saying body is mandatory for PUT and POST

Comment: it should work though, there is no body required in the request as URL has the details. You can just pass an empty JSON as `{ }`

Comment: yes it copied but empty files am i missing something in the header

Comment: recheck the request URI  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/copy-blob#request

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240949/discussion-between-krishna-murthy-and-karthikbhyresh-mt).